# Generating large page structure Liferay 7.0

Tags: liferay, sites

Is there any option to generate large amount of pages for Liferay 7.0?

In documentation (https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-sites) i found only creating pages through GUI.

I would like to use script to generate these pages, is there some sort of CLI or something more useful than mouse clicking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liferay has a script console, were you can make API calls: https://dev.liferay.com/es/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/running-scripts-from-the-script-console

It supports multiple languages, maybe the most interesting for java developers is groovy.

Here there is another link focused on invoking liferay services: https://dev.liferay.com/es/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/invoking-liferay-services-from-scripts.

Basically you should import com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.LayoutLocalServiceUtil and then invoke some of the "add" services, this method for example, will create a layout https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/service/LayoutLocalServiceUtil.java#L101

Answer (score 1):

Liferay has a full API. Watch out for "ServiceBuilder", as that is the component that provides most of the technical basis for it. You'll also need the API-name of pages, which is "Layout". You'll find remote services as `LayoutService`, and "local" services (e.g. no permission checks, only available from within the same VM) as `LayoutLocalService`.

Most likely you'll need to look up examples on their usage. I like to point to the old SevenCogs sample ([revived for 6.1](https://web.liferay.com/de/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/7cogs-is-dead-long-live-7cogs-), but neglected since then)

Another option is to check Liferay's ResourceImporter.